# Ruby Net::HTTP not decoding gzip?

Tags: ruby, nginx, gzip

I have **ruby-1.9.3-p327** with zlib installed. `localhost:80` is the nginx simple test page.

```
require "net/http"
=> true
Net::HTTP::HAVE_ZLIB
=> true

res = Net::HTTP.start("localhost", "80") do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new "/"
  req["accept-encoding"] = "gzip"
  http.request req
end
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>

res.get_fields "content-encoding"
=> ["gzip"]
res.body
=> "\x1F\x8B\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xEC\xBDi..."
```

The body was not decoded. Why?

Comment: It works after switching to **ruby-head** (2.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `http.get` it should decode it automaticlly, but it looks like `request` might not do it for you.

There clearly is code to decompress the gzip request here, but only for the `get` method:
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_327/lib/net/http.rb#L1031

Answer (score 9):

For anyone, who get problem with code worked on ruby 1.9 and failed to work on upgrade to ruby 2.0, just include that code to your project.

```
module HTTPResponseDecodeContentOverride
  def initialize(h,c,m)
    super(h,c,m)
    @decode_content = true
  end
  def body
    res = super
    if self['content-length']
      self['content-length']= res.bytesize
    end
    res
  end
end
module Net
  class HTTPResponse
    prepend HTTPResponseDecodeContentOverride
  end
end
```

Comment: any idea on the root cause of this?

Comment: ruby 2.0 code doesn't do gzip decode until "@decode_content" set to true.

Comment: and @decode_content by default is false. plus without change of content-length, decoded legth are not equal to transferred -- this why i have override that too

Comment: why are you overriding the body method?

Comment: because it required to override content-length; but it unpacket size ready only after super body called

Comment: This code saved my life. Awesome good to know that ruby 2.0 doesn't do gzip decode until @decode_content is set true

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experiments, at least one reason this happens is because of the [right_http_connection](https://github.com/rightscale/right_http_connection) gem. I tested versions 1.3.0 and 1.4.0. This gem monkey patches Net::HTTP and causes problems with decoding GZipped responses.

You can read more about this problem in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/issues/346#issuecomment-37209514).

Comment: Yup, you should check your Gemfile first. Including `right_aws` or `right_http_connection` will break Net::HTTP. These libraries are unmaintained and not 2.0 compatible. `aws-sdk` is the recommended way of using AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I think it does not do it automatically.

To decode, try the following snippet (assuming the response is a StringIO):

```
begin
  Zlib::GzipReader.new(response).read
rescue Zlib::GzipFile::Error, Zlib::Error # Not gzipped
  response.rewind
  response.read
end
```